# crossfilter.isElementFiltered for external datapoints

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I need a convenient way to check if an *arbitrary* datapoint i.e. *not part of the current crossfilter data* would be filtered or not.

The only way I've found is to **add** the datapoint to the crossfilter, **search** the crossfilter for its index, **test** the index using `isElementFiltered` and lastly **remove** the datapoint, which feels shaky at best.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: Crossfilter doesn't offer very many getters for all its parameters, so you end up having to keep track of stuff externally and redundantly. If you're using dc.js, you could probably pull the filters from the charts and test using that info. But it's some work because of all the filter types.